# A question related to maximally non-compact Cartan subalgebra.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

I was looking into the classification of real simple lie algebras from [Araki (1962)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-13/issue-1/On-root-systems-and-an-infinitesimal-classification-of-irreducible-symmetric/ojm/1353055009.full). In page $4$, proposition $1.1$, a criteria is given as to when $\mathfrak{h}^-$ is maximal abelian in $\mathfrak p$ . I could not figure out things from the reference he has given. I started playing around with lie brackets and applying $\sigma$ and $\tau$ in different ways but reached nowhere. Can someone please help me in that direction?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give a little more context? That is, what precisely is the condition and what do you want to know about it?(e.g. why it is equivalent to being maximal in $\mathfrak{p}$)

Comment: Yes! Why $\rho_\alpha=1$ for all $\alpha\in \Delta_c$ is equivalent to maximality ?

Comment: I'm afraid that still isn't clear enough. You want to ask the question in a way that someone who is not looking at the paper and its specific choice of notation can still answer your question

Comment: My assumption would be that $\rho_\alpha$ is the multiplicity of a restricted root with respect to $\mathfrak{h}^-$ and $\Delta_c$ denotes the set of compact roots but I am not sure.